# Why uploadcare is repainting html tag every N ms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle, uploadcare

While using [**Uploadcare**](https://uploadcare.com) file upload widget, I noticed that the Uploadcare script keeps repainting the `HTML` tag.

I am not sure if repainting is the right term, but here is what is happening:
Checking **chrome** `devtools` the `HTML` tag is highlighting, the same behavior when you add/remove an attribute on an element. And it doesn't seem to end, it just goes on and on every N ms. You can check it for yourself on their homepage [Uploadcare.com](https://uploadcare.com/), just open `devtools` and take a look at the `HTML` tag.

Anyone know why it is doing that? What is it calling? Would it cause performance issues to mobile users?

Comment: They're constantly removing and adding the id attribute. You can right-click the html node and select break on attribute modifications to confirm this yourself. _Why_ they're doing it, not sure, if you want to, you can dig through their code, but to me it just sounds like some kind of a hack.

Comment: @Nit nice trick! Whatever their reasons are its very bothersome, i cant edit css styles using the devtools because it keeps on repainting :|

Comment: There is a watch.js that seems to trigger this (and constantly posts to https://mc.yandex.ru/webvisor btw)

Comment: @RetoAebersold I think that is a different script used by their website, not part of the api because I'm not seeing it on my local machine.

Comment: Any work around to stop this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Uploadcare plugin searches for new widgets on the page every 100ms. This is called live initialization. Internally the plugin uses jQuery (which uses Sizzle selector engine) and this is how Sizzle actually works: it adds `id` elements to the root element of the search scope before the querying and remove it after. You can verify this with a simple example:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
  setInterval(function() {
    $.find('[attr]', document.documentElement);
  }, 200);
</script>
```

If you want to avoid flicking, you have two options. You can disable [live initialization](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/widget/#option-live) at all by adding `UPLOADCARE_LIVE = false;` to js code. Or you can add any custom `id` attribute to the `html` tag. Sizzle will not change it.

In the future, we are planning to use `MutationObserver` to watch for the new widgets on the page.

Comment: Any update on the MutationObserver patch? This is driving me nuts.

Comment: @Lee just use one of those methods now to save your sanity. using `ID` on top html element is the easiest.